# Encrypting password for GET DATA

Tags: encryption, passwords, spss

I am using GET DATA command for importing data from SQL server. I would like to use ENCRYPTED sub command. I can encrypt the password using Database Wizard.

I am writing the commands directly in a syntax editor, so I would like to avoid using Database Wizard. Is there any other tool for encrypting the password? I do not want to run the wizard just for the encryption of the password.

A stand alone tool for encrypting password would be nice.